Height function on the sphere is Morse
I'm trying to prove that the height function on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ is a Morse function. Somehow from my onw calculations, I conclude that it's not Morse. Using the embedding with spherical coordinates
$$\iota : (\theta,\varphi) \longmapsto (\sin(\theta)\cos(\varphi),\sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi),\cos(\theta)),$$
the height function is
$$f = \iota \circ \pi_3: (\theta,\varphi) \longmapsto \cos(\theta).$$
I've found the critical points by setting $df_{(\theta,\varphi)} = -\sin(\theta) d\theta$ to zero. This happens if and only if $\theta = 0$ or $\theta = \pi$, meaning the critical points are exactly the poles (as expected, now it gets weird). Now for the Hessian:
$$d^2f_{(\theta,\varphi)} = \left(\begin{matrix} -\cos(\theta) & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right).$$
This matrix is singular everywhere, so is the height function not Morse? The regularity of the hessian is not supposed to depend on the coordinates, so did I do my calculations wrong? Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Spherical coordinates are singular precisely at the poles. In order to understand the behavior of the hessian at the poles, you should use a chart which is well behaved there, i.e. stereographic projection.

Or, far easier computationally, the graph representation over the orthogonal plane.

@J.V.Gaiter Thank you! This was my reminder to check the domains of the charts.
